# Kotlin Serialization - polymorphic deserialization of a sealed hierarchy with JsonContentPolymorphicSerializer as an interceptor

Tags: android, json, kotlin, serialization, kotlinx.serialization

I have a need to deserialize JSON models into a strict hierarchy of classes with a strong forwards compatibility requirement.
This is done with [closed polymorphism](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/master/docs/polymorphism.md#sealed-classes) with `sealed` classes according to documentation.
The models I'm working with look like this:

```kotlin
@Serializable
sealed class BaseChatMessageDto {
    abstract val id: Int
    abstract val localId: Int
    abstract val fromId: Int
    abstract val replyTo: Int?
    abstract val remoteStatus: RemoteStatus?
    abstract val createdAt: Int
    abstract val type: ChatMessageType
}
```

`ChatMessageType` is an enum of message types the client is aware of. A custom serializer ensures that any unknown type is deserialized as `ChatMessageType.UNKNOWN`:

```kotlin
object ChatMessageTypeFallback :
    ForwardCompatibleEnumSerializer<ChatMessageType>(ChatMessageType::class)
@Serializable(ChatMessageTypeFallback::class)
enum class ChatMessageType {
    @SerialName("text")
    TEXT,
    @SerialName("file")
    FILE,
    @SerialName("photo")
    PHOTO,
    @SerialName("sticker")
    STICKER,
    @SerialName("gif")
    GIF,
    @SerialName("task")
    TASK,
    @SerialName("service")
    SERVICE,
    @ForwardsCompatible
    @SerialName("unknown")
    UNKNOWN
}
```

So, the `type` in `BaseChatMessageDto` serves as an implicit type discriminator for the `kotlinx.serialization` compiler plugin. Each of the message types must be deserialized into an object of its own class, for example:

```kotlin
@Serializable
@SerialName("sticker")
data class StickerChatMessageDto(
    override val id: Int,
    @SerialName("local_id")
    override val localId: Int,
    // Override the rest of BaseChatMessageDto

    @SerialName("sticker_id")
    val stickerId: Int?,
    // Other fields specific for "sticker" type

    // Override ChatMessageWithReactionsDto field
    override val reactions: List<Reaction>,
): BaseChatMessageDto(), ChatMessageWithReactionsDto
```

Some types like `FILE` and `PHOTO` are considered rich messages, and have their own superclass:

```kotlin
@Serializable
sealed class RichChatMessageDto: BaseChatMessageDto(), ChatMessageWithReactionsDto {
    abstract override val id: Int
    @SerialName("local_id")
    abstract override val localId: Int
    abstract override val type: ChatMessageType
    // Override the rest of BaseChatMessageDto

    abstract val text: String
    // Other abstract members of RichChatMessageDto

    // Override ChatMessageWithReactionsDto field
    abstract override val reactions: List<Reaction>?
}

@Serializable
@SerialName("file")
data class FileChatMessageDto(
    override val type: ChatMessageType = ChatMessageType.FILE,
    // Override everything else from RichChatMessageDto
): RichChatMessageDto()
```

`UnknownChatMessageDto` provides forwards compatibility by being deserialized into when an unknown `ChatMessageType` is encountered:

```kotlin
@Serializable
@SerialName("unknown")
data class UnknownChatMessageDto(
    // Override everything.
): BaseChatMessageDto()
```

But there is a very special case in this logic - deleted messages. Server-side they are discriminated not by `type`, but by `status`. If `status` is `DELETED`, then the base model is returned regardless of its `type`. So I need to create a deserialization interceptor of sorts, that will look at `status` at first, use `DeletedMessageDto.serializer()` if necessary, otherwise proceed with default deserialization pipeline. As far as I'm aware, `JsonContentPolymorphicSerializer` is designed specifically for this, so:

```kotlin
@Serializable
data class DeletedChatMessageDto(
    // Override everything
): BaseChatMessageDto()
```

```kotlin
@Serializable(
    with = DeletedMessageInterceptorSerializer::class
)
sealed class BaseChatMessageDto {
    // ...
}

object DeletedMessageInterceptorSerializer: JsonContentPolymorphicSerializer<BaseChatMessageDto>(
    BaseChatMessageDto::class
) {
    override fun selectDeserializer(element: JsonElement): DeserializationStrategy<BaseChatMessageDto> {
        val status = try {
            val primitive = element.jsonObject["status"]?.jsonPrimitive
            // Parse status into enum
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            RemoteStatus.UNKNOWN
        }
        return when (status) {
            RemoteStatus.DELETED -> DeletedChatMessageDto.serializer()
            else -> PolymorphicSerializer(BaseChatMessageDto::class)
        }
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work as expected. `DeletedChatMessageDto` seem to be deserialized fine, but for other types it fails:

```
kotlinx.serialization.json.internal.JsonDecodingException: Polymorphic serializer was not found for class discriminator 'text'
```

If I provide a `SerializersModule` to my `Json` like this:

```kotlin
serializersModule += SerializersModule {
    polymorphic(BaseChatMessageDto::class) {
        defaultDeserializer {
            UnknownChatMessageDto.serializer()
        }
    }
}
```

Then `DeletedChatMessageDto`s *are* deserialized fine, but all other types are unsurprisingly deserialized as `UnknownChatMessageDto`.
If I register subclasses explicitly:

```kotlin
serializersModule += SerializersModule {
    polymorphic(BaseChatMessageDto::class) {
        subclass(TextChatMessageDto::class)
        subclass(FileChatMessageDto::class)
        subclass(PhotoChatMessageDto::class)
    }
}
```

Then another exception is thrown:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Polymorphic serializer for class <package>.FileChatMessageDto (Kotlin reflection is not available) has property 'type' that conflicts with JSON class discriminator. You can either change class discriminator in JsonConfiguration, rename property with @SerialName annotation or fall back to array polymorphism
```

If I instead try to use a suggestion from @simon-jacobs about using a `typealias` like this:

```kotlin
typealias BaseChatMessageDto =
    @Serializable(DeletedMessageInterceptorSerializer::class)
    BaseChatMessageDtoPlain

@Serializable
sealed class BaseChatMessageDtoPlain {
    // ...
}

// I tried both BaseChatMessageDtoPlain and BaseChatMessageDto here
object DeletedMessageInterceptorSerializer: JsonContentPolymorphicSerializer<BaseChatMessageDtoPlain>(
    BaseChatMessageDtoPlain::class
) {
    override fun selectDeserializer(element: JsonElement): DeserializationStrategy<BaseChatMessageDtoPlain> {
        val status = // ...
        return when (status) {
            RemoteStatus.DELETED -> DeletedChatMessageDto.serializer()
            else -> BaseChatMessageDtoPlain.serializer()
        }
    }

}
```

Then the serializer **is** called when `BaseChatMessageDto` is a property of another serializable type, but not called for a Retrofit call that returns a `List<BaseChatMessageDto>`, which results in exceptions for  deleted messages:

```
kotlinx.serialization.MissingFieldException: Field 'text' is required for type with serial name 'text', but it was missing at path: $[1]
```

I can't quite figure out why `DeletedMessageInterceptorSerializer` is not applied through a `typealias` for this particular call.

I am aware that I could use `JsonContentPolymorphicSerializer` to select a serializer based on `type` by hand, but I want to offload as much logic to the compiler plugin for type safety, code clarity and less places a mistake could be made.
What am I doing wrong here? Is `PolymorphicSerializer(BaseChatMessageDto::class)` not the way to proceed with closed polymorphic deserialization pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

##### The `type` discriminator

`type` is used as the default JSON key for polymorphic serialization. As far as I am aware it might be possible to get polymorphic serialization to work with that property name occupied by an enum, but you are making life difficult for yourself by doing so.

I would suggest not using an enum class at all, or at least don't use it the `type` property for it. It would appear to have no real functionality in your server-side code anyhow, since you have a corresponding class hierarchy.

Instead, leave `type` blank in `BaseChatMessageDto`. The serializer can pick the `type` key up in the JSON itself and use it to choose the correct subclass provided those subclasses have serial names corresponding to the values `type` can be (something you look to have already taken care of).

##### Using `PolymorphicSerializer` and alternatives

> Is `PolymorphicSerializer(BaseChatMessageDto::class)` not the way to proceed with closed polymorphic deserialization pipeline?

No, it's not. This serializer is associated with defining a `SerializersModule`, as alluded to by the [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.serialization/kotlinx-serialization-core/kotlinx.serialization/-polymorphic-serializer/)<sup>1</sup>. To use this you would need to register each of the subclasses (in conjunction with removing the `type` property as described above).

You can still get it to work without a module though by having a different serializer specified as the default one for `BaseChatMessageDto` to the one you use to deserialize an incoming JSON object.

To do this, leave `BaseChatMessageDto` with its plain `@Serializable` annotation and refer to this in `DeletedMessageInterceptorSerializer`:

```
return when (status) {
    RemoteStatus.DELETED -> DeletedChatMessageDto.serializer()
    else -> BaseChatMessageDto.serializer()
}
```

And use your inteceptor serializer when you are actually decoding a message<sup>2</sup>:

```
Json.decodeFromString(DeletedMessageInterceptorSerializer, incomingMessage)
```

---

<sup>1</sup>The sealed class counterpart to `PolymorphicSerializer` is [`SealedClassSerializer`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.serialization/kotlinx-serialization-core/kotlinx.serialization/-sealed-class-serializer/), which you could instantiate by hand. However I  think the approach suggested above would be more typical rather than using this internal API.

<sup>2</sup>Or if your message is decoded as part of a larger class hierarchy, you might instead specify `DeletedMessageInterceptorSerializer` by annotating the appropriate enclosing class property.

Comment: You seem to have assumed I control the server. I apologize for not clarifying this in my question, but I do not, in fact control server-side schemas. I'm working entirely with an Android client.

Comment: I'm not having any problems with using an `enum` as a type discriminator, since it comes in a form of a string and gets deserialized into an enum *after* the lib runtime choses a concrete class serializer from a list of `BaseChatMessageDto` descendants. Moreover, I need it in my local data source to discriminate between types of messages after I query for them, so I need it exactly where it is.

Comment: I'm not actually calling `Json.decodeFromString` by hand - Retrofit calls the decoder for me, so I can't control what serializer it uses in all places. For example, a `@GET` request that returns a `List<BaseChatMessageDto>`. Even if I can, it would be error-prone to annotate every usage of `BaseChatMessageDto` as a property of another serializable type with `@Serializable(DeletedMessageInterceptorSerializer::class)`.

Comment: For now I went with selecting a serializer based on `type` in `DeletedMessageInterceptorSerializer` to unblock myself, but I would **love** to make it work as I intended.

Comment: (1) I haven't assumed you control the server: I was aware you might not. (2) I suggest you get it to work without using `type` as an enum first and you can experiment with changing it back afterwards. It would be a shame to refuse to try this when it appears to be an issue. Further, from what I have read, you don't appear to need the enum because the class of the enclosing object tells you the same information. (3) If you can't annotate the relevant usages of the `BaseChatMessageDto` serializer then you can use `SealedClassSerializer` which I described.

Comment: Another possibility by the way to include a specific serializer when a type appears is to write a type alias with that serializer eg `typealias BaseChatMessageDtoPlusDeleted = @Serializable(with = DeletedMessageInterceptorSerializer::class) BaseChatMessageDto`. Then you've got to choose the typealias instead. Or, with this technique you could change the name of `BaseChatMessageDto` to eg `BaseChatMessageDtoPlain` and use the typelias `BaseChatMessageDto  = @Serializable(with = DeletedMessageInterceptorSerializer::class) BaseChatMessageDtoPlain` everywhere. That would not be error prone.

Comment: Wow, that's smart. Thank you for your help and suggestions, I'll try it and get back when it's not night in my timezone

Comment: Ok, I tried it. The nights are long where I live. This suggestion could work, but I encountered problems with it. I updated my question with my findings

Comment: "Then the serializer is called when BaseChatMessageDto is a property of another serializable type, but not called for a Retrofit call that returns a List<BaseChatMessageDto>" That sounds like it's working to me, but now the problem is what works with Retrofit. Probably better the scope of another question (and not a library I'm familiar with).